# formik onchange event handler not populating material ui TEXTFIELD

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, material-ui, formik

hello i am  working on a react project and currently handling the authentication process and i am using material ui and formik for validation and handling input change, but the issue here is, my onchange formik handler in my TEXTFIELD if not working why? and how can i resolve this issue. im using two formik instances login formik and register formik is this also a better approach?

```
 const loginformik=useFormik({
        initialValues:{
            // firstName:"",
            // lastName:"",
            email:"",
            password:"",
            
        },
        onSubmit:(values=>console.log(values))
    })

    const registerformik=useFormik({
        initialValues:{
            firstName:"",
            lastName:"",
            email:"",
            password:"",
        },
        onSubmit:(values=>console.log(values))
    })

<form className="signup input-group" id="signup" ref={registerRef}  onSubmit={registerformik.handleSubmit}>

                <TextField 
                        fullWidth sx={{ width:'100%', }}
                        // helperText="enter email"
                        id="email"
                        label="Email"
                        
                        name="email"
                        type='email'
                        className="auth_input"
                        value={registerformik.values.email}
                        onChange={registerformik.handleChange}
                        
                        
                        />


                <TextField 
                        fullWidth sx={{ width:'100%',marginTop:'5%', }}
                        // helperText="enter email"
                        id="firstName"
                        label="FirstName"
                    
                        name="name"
                        type='text'
                        className="auth_input"
                        defaultValue={registerformik.values.firstName}
                        onChange={registerformik.handleChange}

                        />


                    <TextField 
                        fullWidth sx={{ width:'100%',marginTop:'5%' }}
                        // helperText="enter email"
                        id="lastName"
                        label="LastName"
                        // defaultValue=""
                        name="last_name"
                        type='text'
                        className="auth_input"
                        defaultValue={registerformik.values.lastName}
                        onChange={registerformik.handleChange}

                        /> 



                    <TextField 
                        fullWidth 
                        sx={{ width:'100% ',marginTop:'5% '  }}
                    
                        type='password'
                        // helperText="enter password"
                        id="password"
                        label="Password"
                        defaultValue=""
                        name="password"
                        className="auth_input"
                        value={registerformik.values.password}
                        onChange={registerformik.handleChange}
                        inputProps={{
                            endAdornment:(
                                    <InputAdornment position="end">
                                        
                                        <IconButton
                                        aria-label="toggle password"
                                        onClick={handleClickShowPassword}
                                        onMouseDown={handleMouseDownPassword}
                                        edge="end"
                                        
                                
                                        >
                                            <VisibilityIcon />
                                        {/* {showPassword ? <VisibilityIcon /> : <VisibilityOffIcon />} */}
                                        </IconButton>
                                    </InputAdornment>
                            ),
                        }}
                        
                        
                        />

                        <Button variant="contained" type='submit' color="success" sx={{ width:'30% ', marginTop:'3%' }}>
                        Sign up
                        </Button>
                    
                        
                    
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

you're just using wrong `name` attributes inside your textField, the name value must match the name of your target formik property:
for example `name="name"` becomes `name="firstName"`

```html
<TextField
        fullWidth
        sx={{ width: "100%", marginTop: "5%" }}
        // helperText="enter email"
        id="firstName"
        label="FirstName"
        name="firstName"
        type="text"
        className="auth_input"
        defaultValue={registerformik.values.firstName}
        onChange={registerformik.handleChange}
/>
```

and for your lastName field :

```html
<TextField
        fullWidth
        sx={{ width: "100%", marginTop: "5%" }}
        // helperText="enter email"
        id="lastName"
        label="LastName"
        name="lastName"
        type="text"
        className="auth_input"
        defaultValue={registerformik.values.lastName}
        onChange={registerformik.handleChange}
/>
```

lastely, yes it's a good idea to use two different formik instances because each one is serving a different need or use case.